# Connecting to several password protected workbooks in Excel

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

I'm creating a master sheet to pool data from 16 password protected workbooks, if it possible to run a macro to just enter the passwords upon opening the master file? I don't want to build the password into every reference, just the initial opening.

I don't want to open the source files, just enter passwords (when opening the master, a prompt for each password comes up sequentially)

I tried recording a macro while entering the passwords but it didn't capture them.

Is this actually possible? Are there any commands like `externalWorkbook.password = "hunter2"`?

I know I've seen some code on here before dealing with passwords but I've been unable to find it today...

I'm a 100% VBA novice, so any help at all is hugely appreciated!

edit: if it helps with example code, the master file is in the same shared folder as all the source files, and the file path is approximately `\\url.gov.uk\server\workgroup\productivity\team` and each file is just the user's first name, e.g. Ann, Bob, Cat, Dot etc.

Comment: @Santosh I don't need to open the workbooks or edit them in any way, the password is just required to reference them in formulae in the master workbook

Answer (score 0):

```
Workbooks.Open filename,,,,password
```

Is what you need, you can set this to be an excel workbook object also

```
dim x as excel.workbook
set x=Workbooks.Open (filename,,,,password)
```

Comment: I don't need (or want) to actually open the source files, just make it so that the team manager doesn't need to type over a dozen passwords every time they want to check the team's overall productivity.

Comment: So you just want to get the data from a password protected workbook?

Comment: Exactly that, but with 16 password protected workbooks at once - ideally I just want a macro to input the passwords

Comment: Unfortunately not, I think it's something to do with how the whole network is set up (government IT, is there any hell more fresh?)  Unless I'm mistaken, to link them I need a username and a password, none of the usernames I can think of to try (I've been fairly thorough) have allowed me to make a connection.

Comment: Do you know the passwords?

Comment: Yes, as does the team leader who will be accessing the file when it's complete, I'm just trying to stop them from having to enter 17 passwords every time they open the file, though if it's absolutely the only option then it can be so.

Comment: I think you'll need to open the workbooks, as stated with the password, but not visible? grab the data, then close.  The password stops an ADO-SQL connection also I believe.  You can hard code the passwords or have a sheet to look them up off, hidden of course :)

Comment: Hard coding the passwords would be fine, but how might a I go about that? As it stands I don't even know the equivalent of 'Hello world' in VBA